# Application of Neural Network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I asked a question a few days before but I guess it was a little too complicated and I don't expect to get any answer.

My problem is that I need to use ANN for classification. I've read that much better cost function (or loss function as some books specify) is the cross-entropy, that is `J(w) = -1/m * sum_i(   yi*ln(hw(xi)) + (1-yi)*ln(1 - hw(xi))   )`; `i` indicates the no. data from training matrix `X`. I tried to apply it in MATLAB but I find it really difficult. There are couple things I don't know:

- should I sum each outputs given all training data (i = 1, ... N,  where N is number of inputs for training)
- is the gradient calculated correctly
- is the numerical gradient (gradAapprox) calculated correctly.

I have following MATLAB codes. I realise I may ask for trivial thing but anyway I hope someone can give me some clues how to find the problem. I suspect the problem is to calculate gradients.

Many thanks.

Main script:

```
close all
clear all

L = @(x) (1 + exp(-x)).^(-1);
NN = @(x,theta) theta{2}*[ones(1,size(x,1));L(theta{1}*[ones(size(x,1),1) x]')];

% theta = [10 -30 -30];
x = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
y = [0.9 0.1 0.1 0.1]';

theta0 = 2*rand(9,1)-1;
options = optimset('gradObj','on','Display','iter');
thetaVec = fminunc(@costFunction,theta0,options,x,y);
theta = cell(2,1);
theta{1} = reshape(thetaVec(1:6),[2 3]);
theta{2} = reshape(thetaVec(7:9),[1 3]);

NN(x,theta)'
```

Cost function:

```
function [jVal,gradVal,gradApprox] = costFunction(thetaVec,x,y)
persistent index;

%     1 x x
%     1 x x
%     1 x x
% x = 1 x x
%     1 x x
%     1 x x
%     1 x x

m = size(x,1);

if isempty(index) || index > size(x,1)
    index = 1;
end

L = @(x) (1 + exp(-x)).^(-1);
NN = @(x,theta) theta{2}*[ones(1,size(x,1));L(theta{1}*[ones(size(x,1),1) x]')];

theta = cell(2,1);
theta{1} = reshape(thetaVec(1:6),[2 3]);
theta{2} = reshape(thetaVec(7:9),[1 3]);
Dew = cell(2,1);
DewApprox = cell(2,1);

% Forward propagation
a0 = x(index,:)';
z1 = theta{1}*[1;a0];
a1 = L(z1);
z2 = theta{2}*[1;a1];
a2 = L(z2);

% Back propagation
d2 = 1/m*(a2 - y(index))*L(z2)*(1-L(z2));
Dew{2} = [1;a1]*d2;
d1 = [1;a1].*(1 - [1;a1]).*theta{2}'*d2;
Dew{1} = [1;a0]*d1(2:end)';

% NNRes = NN(x,theta)';
% jVal = -1/m*sum(NNRes-y)*NNRes*(1-NNRes);
jVal = -1/m*(a2 - y(index))*a2*(1-a2);
gradVal = [Dew{1}(:);Dew{2}(:)];

gradApprox = CalcGradApprox(0.0001);

index = index + 1;

function output = CalcGradApprox(epsilon)
    output = zeros(size(gradVal));
    for n=1:length(thetaVec)
        thetaVecMin = thetaVec;
        thetaVecMax = thetaVec;
        thetaVecMin(n) = thetaVec(n) - epsilon;
        thetaVecMax(n) = thetaVec(n) + epsilon;

        thetaMin = cell(2,1);
        thetaMax = cell(2,1);
        thetaMin{1} = reshape(thetaVecMin(1:6),[2 3]);
        thetaMin{2} = reshape(thetaVecMin(7:9),[1 3]);
        thetaMax{1} = reshape(thetaVecMax(1:6),[2 3]);
        thetaMax{2} = reshape(thetaVecMax(7:9),[1 3]);

        a2min = NN(x(index,:),thetaMin)';
        a2max = NN(x(index,:),thetaMax)';
        jValMin = -1/m*(a2min-y(index))*a2min*(1-a2min);
        jValMax = -1/m*(a2max-y(index))*a2max*(1-a2max);
        output(n) = (jValMax - jValMin)/2/epsilon;
    end
end
end
```

---

EDIT:
Below I present the correct version of my costFunction for those who may be interested.

```
function [jVal,gradVal,gradApprox] = costFunction(thetaVec,x,y)
    m = size(x,1);

    L = @(x) (1 + exp(-x)).^(-1);
    NN = @(x,theta) L(theta{2}*[ones(1,size(x,1));L(theta{1}*[ones(size(x,1),1) x]')]);

    theta = cell(2,1);
    theta{1} = reshape(thetaVec(1:6),[2 3]);
    theta{2} = reshape(thetaVec(7:9),[1 3]);
    Delta = cell(2,1);
    Delta{1} = zeros(size(theta{1}));
    Delta{2} = zeros(size(theta{2}));
    D = cell(2,1);
    D{1} = zeros(size(theta{1}));
    D{2} = zeros(size(theta{2}));
    jVal = 0;

    for in = 1:size(x,1)
        % Forward propagation
        a1 = [1;x(in,:)']; % added bias to a0
        z2 = theta{1}*a1;
        a2 = [1;L(z2)]; % added bias to a1
        z3 = theta{2}*a2;
        a3 = L(z3);
        % Back propagation
        d3 = a3 - y(in);
        d2 = theta{2}'*d3.*a2.*(1 - a2);
        Delta{2} = Delta{2} + d3*a2';
        Delta{1} = Delta{1} + d2(2:end)*a1';
        jVal = jVal + sum(  y(in)*log(a3) + (1-y(in))*log(1-a3)  );
    end
    D{1} = 1/m*Delta{1};
    D{2} = 1/m*Delta{2};

    jVal = -1/m*jVal;
    gradVal = [D{1}(:);D{2}(:)];
    gradApprox = CalcGradApprox(x(in,:),0.0001);



    % Nested function to calculate gradApprox
    function output = CalcGradApprox(x,epsilon)
        output = zeros(size(thetaVec));
        for n=1:length(thetaVec)
            thetaVecMin = thetaVec;
            thetaVecMax = thetaVec;
            thetaVecMin(n) = thetaVec(n) - epsilon;
            thetaVecMax(n) = thetaVec(n) + epsilon;

            thetaMin = cell(2,1);
            thetaMax = cell(2,1);
            thetaMin{1} = reshape(thetaVecMin(1:6),[2 3]);
            thetaMin{2} = reshape(thetaVecMin(7:9),[1 3]);
            thetaMax{1} = reshape(thetaVecMax(1:6),[2 3]);
            thetaMax{2} = reshape(thetaVecMax(7:9),[1 3]);

            a3min = NN(x,thetaMin)';
            a3max = NN(x,thetaMax)';
            jValMin = 0;
            jValMax = 0;
            for inn=1:size(x,1)
                jValMin = jValMin + sum(  y(inn)*log(a3min) + (1-y(inn))*log(1-a3min)  );
                jValMax = jValMax + sum(  y(inn)*log(a3max) + (1-y(inn))*log(1-a3max)  );
            end
            jValMin = 1/m*jValMin;
            jValMax = 1/m*jValMax;
            output(n) = (jValMax - jValMin)/2/epsilon;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've only had a quick eyeball over your code. Here are some pointers.

**Q1**

> should I sum each outputs given all training data (i = 1, ... N, where
>   N is number of inputs for training)

If you are talking in relation to the cost function, it is normal to sum and normalise by the number of training examples in order to provide comparison between.

I can't tell from the code whether you have a vectorised implementation which will change the answer. Note that the `sum` function will only sum up a single dimension at a time - meaning if you have a (M by N) array, sum will result in a 1 by N array.

The cost function should have a scalar output.

**Q2**

> is the gradient calculated correctly

The gradient is not calculated correctly - specifically the deltas look wrong. Try following  [Andrew Ng's notes](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http://cs.uky.edu/~jacobs/classes/2012_learning/lectures/neuralnets_ng.pdf&ei=14ZJUqbpELKM7AbRkoDICw&usg=AFQjCNF6AF9QfemV4UcbxayMprLmXkOLDg&sig2=RN2xQIBYAb9o3rBYIqj2Dw&bvm=bv.53217764,d.ZGU) [PDF] they are very good.

**Q3**

> is the numerical gradient (gradAapprox) calculated correctly.

This line looks a bit suspect. Does this make more sense?

```
output(n) = (jValMax - jValMin)/(2*epsilon);
```

EDIT: I actually can't make heads or tails of your gradient approximation. You should only use forward propagation and small tweaks in the parameters to compute the gradient. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Luke. First of all. Thanks for you answer. I'll go through the notes you've provided. At the moment, I will only comment to Q3 that your expression is equivalent to mine in MATLAB but visually yours look clearer. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Luke, Thank you for the notes. Everything works now and the gradients calculated analytically and numerically are very similar which means the model is trained correctly :) Best wishes, Ziko